# f and g are bounded . if 1/g is bounded, then f/g is bounded.

Tags: functions, proof-writing, boundary-value-problem

I would like some help understanding how to go about this question. I think that f/g is not bounded, but I cannot figure how to show that f/g is not bounded.

Comment: Write $f/g=fh$ where $h=1/g$. The product of two bounded functions is ...

Answer (score 4):

We have $|f| < P$, $|g| < Q$, and $|1/g| < R$ for some $P$, $Q$, and $R$, so

$$\left|\frac{f}{g} \right|= \left| f\frac{1}{g} \right| < PR.$$

Comment: so are we saying that f/g is bounded ?

Comment: @Zero That is correct.